# Elastic Search Nested Aggregation size

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested aggregation that is only returning 10 results. I want it to return 1000 results. However, I'm not sure where to to specify the size. My mapping looks like (its in YAML but is processed to json, dont worry about that)

```
      mappings:
        datainfo:
          properties:
            filterValues:
              type: string
            metadata:
              properties:
                isPrimary:
                  type: boolean
                name:
                  index: not_analyzed
                  type: string
                source:
                  enabled: false
                  type: object
                type:
                  index: not_analyzed
                  type: string
                val:
                  index: not_analyzed
                  type: string
              type: nested
            source:
              enabled: false
              type: object
            title:
              type: string
```

My query looks something like

```
{
    "query": "<some query>",
    "aggs": {
        "series": {
            "nested": { "path": "metadata" },
            "aggs": {
                 "val": {
                    "terms": { "field": "metadata.val" },
                    "aggs": {
                        "type": {
                            "terms": { "field": "metadata.name" }
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Where do I put a "size" field in order to make this return X results? It currently only returns 10

Comment: Do you want to specify the number of results from the main query or do you want to get the data grouped from the aggregation hits and specify the number of results per bucket? If it's the total size then here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-from-size.html

Answer (score 0):

To specify the number of results of the query, you can use [size, or size with range:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-from-size.html)

```
{
"query": "<some query>",
"size": 1000,
"aggs": {
    "series": {
        "nested": { "path": "metadata" },
        "aggs": {
             "val": {
                "terms": { "field": "metadata.val" },
                "aggs": {
                    "type": {
                        "terms": { "field": "metadata.name" }
                    }
                }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

}

To specify the number of results on the aggregation buckets you can use [Top Hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) (example from link):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "top-tags": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "tags",
            "size": 3
        },
        "aggs": {
            "top_tag_hits": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "last_activity_date": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "_source": {
                        "includes": [
                            "title"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size" : 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

One recommended approach if you only need the aggregated results is to specify a size of 0 for the query results which eliminates the first fetch and consequently performs better.